# How to place a TextView on a CustomView programatically?

Tags: android

In my application I design a custom view, and here is the code

```
public class Tunnel extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public Tunnel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x++) {
            canvas.drawLine(x, (float) upperBound(x), x, (float) lowerBound(x), paint);
        }
        setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    private double upperBound(double x) {
        return 50 * Math.sin(x / 50) + 400;
    }

    private double lowerBound(double x) {
        return 50 * Math.sin(x / 50) + 600;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And it looks like this

[image]

Now what I need to do, is add a custom TextView on this view, which will show some text. As far as i realise, my constructor should look like this

```
    public Tunnel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setX(200);
        tv.setY(200);
        //todo show the textView
    }
```

But i don't know what to write next. How can i apply the textView to my view?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 public Tunnel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnTouchListener(this);
        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setX(200);
        tv.setY(200);
        tv.setText("Text");
        TheCustomView.addView(tv);
    }
```

Comment: yeah i thought it would look something like this, but what is myLayout? I have no layout defined here

Answer (score 0):

I inherited my custom view from a linear layout, set it to do the onDraw method, and it worked for me

```
public class Tunnel extends LinearLayout implements View.OnTouchListener {

        Paint paint = new Paint();

        TextView tv;

        public Tunnel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setOnTouchListener(this);
            setWillNotDraw(false);
            tv = new TextView(getContext());
            tv.setX(450);
            tv.setY(800);
            tv.setTextSize(20f);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            addView(tv);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (int x = 0; x < canvas.getWidth(); x++) {
                canvas.drawLine(x, (float) upperBound(x), x, (float) lowerBound(x), paint);
            }
              setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        private double upperBound(double x) {
            return 50 * Math.sin(x / 50) + 400;
        }

        private double lowerBound(double x) {
            return 50 * Math.sin(x / 50) + 600;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```